# Redirect apache2

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, apache2

Есть сервер на `Xenial 16.04`, установил `laravel`, делаю редирект с `/project_name/public` на `/project_name/`:
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/project_name.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@your_domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_name/public/
ServerName your_domain.com
ServerAlias www.your_domain.com 
<Directory /var/www/html/project_name/>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/your_domain.com-error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/your_domain.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

`/var/www/html/project_name/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Что предпринимал:
менял`.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !project/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /project/public/$1 [L]
```

и в конфиге:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_name/
Redirect permanent your_domain.com/ your_domain.com/public/
```

Но все тщетно.

Comment: `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project_name/public/` корень сайта. И открывая главную сайта вы попадаете в эту папку, а не в `project_name`. Редирект вы в `project_name` не сделаете, так как она не доступна из вне и это правильно.

Comment: @Visman я уже пробовал менять на `/var/www/html/project_name/`

Comment: А зачем? Только файлы из `public` должны смотреть в мир, все остальное должно быть скрыто.

Comment: @Visman но тогда ведь стартовая страница доступна не по `/project_name/`, а по `project_name/public`. Я переименовал в корне проекта `server.php` в `index.php` - это помогло, но в этом случае, насколько я понимаю, нужно будет все `assets` менять